# How to install Firefox to home directory on Solaris?

Tags: solaris, firefox, home

How can I install `Firefox` to my home directory on `Solaris`?

I do not have root or administrator access.

Comment: If you're going to downvote a question, tell the questioner *why*.  Beginners often don't even know the proper terms to search for when they have a problem to solve.  Blindly downvoting posters isn't useful at all.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download a tarball from https://unixpackages.com/packages/mozilla
2. Untar the tarball in your home directory
3. `~/path/to/firefox`

Comment: What does the third step mean?

Comment: `~` is a substitute for your home directory. `path/to/firefox` is to be replaced with the actual path of your Firefox installation.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the package from the sunfreeware mirror (old unix packages and free webpage): http://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/sun-freeware/mozilla/

Once you have it, upload it to /tmp or any directory where you like and install it link this:

```
1- Uncompress
$ bunzip2 /tmp/firefox-10.0.2.en-US.solaris-10-fcs-sparc-pkg.bz2

2- Install
$ pkgadd -d /tmp/firefox-10.0.2.en-US.solaris-10-fcs-sparc-pkg -R /export/home/user/
```

Bad news are: 
Probably this will not work, firefox need libraries that must be installed as root.
You can't use pkgrm to uninstall the software you must delete the directories.
You have to run firefox like `/export/home/user/opt/sfw/bin/firefox` since the software is not installed in the root base directory.